# Jump into interface in Eclipse by shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to jump from an class (method) that implement an interface (method) to the interface method by a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse.

Is there a shortcut to do this?

Comment: Press Ctrl and click on the interface name (after keyword implements), it will open the interface.

Comment: But I'm searching for a shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto to "Window" -> "Preferences" -> "General" -> "Keys

There search for **"Open Super Implementation"** and create a key binding for that.

[image: Eclipse: "Open Super Implementation"]

Comment: This is a great command, I didn't know this! It *can* be solved with Quick Type Hierarchy also, but it takes a few more key presses.

Comment: Quick Type Hierarchy is also good because it lets you jump both up and down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F4</kbd> with focus on the method.

Comment: It does not jump from the class method to the interface method.

Comment: sorry, the only popup you can show is `F4` not `F3` :)

Comment: It shows you the `Type Hierarchy` View, and from that navigate the Interface and its method (having `show the super type hierarchy` button selected).

Comment: Is there also the possibility to jump to the method in the interface? I can not see, how this will work.

Answer (score 1):

answer to the question described in comments under flafoux answer, but to clearly explain the answer, giving here...

1. Select Method in implementation and Press <kbd>F4</kbd> button
2. It shows **Type Hierarchy**
3. On Type Hierarchy, on the top section click on toolbar button **Show  Supertype hierarchy** (this step is only required once)
4. On Type Hierarchy, detail section shows Interface method
5. Click on the (automatically selected) method

Answer (score 0):

Use Quick Type Hierachy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

When this is used while the cursor is inside a method you will get a popup which lets you select among the *superclasses* which declare the current method. By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> again while the popup is still open it lets you select among implemented *interfaces* which declare the current method.

Comment: Does not work. I want to see the interfaces / jump to the interface (method).

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE: This command can do exactly that. I've added more information.